# can't get my script tags to function in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I'm making a credit card info forms for a webpage and the scripts I found online only work with Safari to make the style I want.

This is what I copied and pasted into the head of my html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">


  <!-- Start BounceX tag. Deploy at the beginning of document head. -->
        <script>
        (function(d) {
            var e = d.createElement('script');
            e.src = d.location.protocol + '//bounceexchange.com/tag/426/i.js';
            e.async = true;
            d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
        }(document));
        </script>
<!-- End BounceX Tag-->

    <!--Optimizely  -->
  <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/191337197.js"></script>


  <!-- ClickTale Top part -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript%20src='" +
                            (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ?
                            'https://clicktalecdn.sslcs.cdngc.net/' :
                            'http://cdn.clicktale.net/') +
                            "www11/phc/e9344b9e-32db-42a2-989b-468e39690d0a.js'%20type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<!-- ClickTale end of Top part -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxyhkd3j/

Here is how it looks in Safari vs Chrome.

What I want, in Safari: http ://imgur.com/dOl03G1

What I am getting in Chrome: http ://imgur.com/nYwAcMO

Comment: You are using 2 jquery mobile libraries and 2 jquery libraries.  I havnt tested your code, but they will conflict.  Try only using one of each.

Comment: Also, can you post your html?

Comment: Screenshot looks like insecure content warning on Chrome (shield icon on address bar). Might be HTTPS issue (in which case you will want to use relative links or strictly SSL).

Answer (score 1):

You should only be placing this in your header.   Only one jquery, one jquery mobile, and one jquery mobile css.  You used duplicates and there will be conflict problems.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```